# tkinter and pygame problems with entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame, tk-toolkit

I want to make a "Music Hub" so to speak, where I could have all my music in one place all I would have to do it type in the song name then press play. I've almost achieved it, but I'm getting an error for my entry in tkinter. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import pygame
import tkinter

root = Tk()
f1 = tkinter.Frame(root, height=100, width=100)
f1.pack()
root.title("Test")

e = Entry(f1)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

s = e.get()

def song():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(s+".mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
def pause():
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
def resume():
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()



b = Button(f1, text="Play Song", command=song)
b.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

b2 = Button(f1, text="Pause", command=pause)
b2.pack()

b3 = Button(f1, text="Resume", command=resume)
b3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I'm getting the error "pygame.error: Couldn't open '.mp3'", so that must mean that the input from the entry isn't going through. All help appreciated thanks!

Comment: `s = e.get()` assigns the entries current value to `s`. Which is initially nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out a solution. instead of making the e.get() a variable, i just put it into the pygame statement.

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(s+".mp3")
```

changed to

```
pygame.mixer.music.load((e.get())+".mp3")
```

and it works

Comment: This is the solution because it makes the `song` method to get the entry value whenever it is called, ergo when the button is pressed. As opposed to getting entry's initial value.